# How to avoid StaleElementReferenceError when getting elements from different page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get all the results from a race. The website shows 50 rows/page.
I navigate to the next page (same URL with suffix #page-x) using selenium, but I get a StaleElementReferenceException error whenever I try to find elements (cells of the table = td) on the next page.

I tried to close the driver between the steps to get just one list of elements at a time. I've also tried to load the pages separately with the URL+suffix, but it doesn't load correctly. I've tried building separate lists (at first I wanted one big list with all the results).

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "https://tickets.justrun.ca/quidchrono.php?a=qcResult&raceid=8444"

#The block under works well and I get a list of cells as intended.
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
course = []
for i in range(len(elements)):
    course.append(elements[i].text)

to_2 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("2")
to_2.click()
print(driver.current_url)

#I'm trying similar code for the next chunk, but it doesn't work.
elements2 = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
print(len(elements2))
print(elements2[5].text)
course2 = []
for i in range(len(elements2)):
    course2.append(elements2[i].text)
driver.close()
```

I would expect a new list (course2), with the results of the second page, but I get a stale element error. When I print the current URL, the result is as expected. When I print the len(elements2), it's also OK. Looks like the problem is when I try to get the text of an element.

Comment: The elements need to be on the current page. Did you verify that the second page loaded before you got the list of `<td>`? If not then you probably got pg1...

Comment: I've added print(driver.current_url) after to_2.click() and I get the expected result : https://tickets.justrun.ca/quidchrono.php?a=qcResult&raceid=8444#page-2 At this point, I see the results 51-100 in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution-1:**

Using `BeautifulSoup` and `selenium`, [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) is waiting for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code. for more details about [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://tickets.justrun.ca/quidchrono.php?a=qcResult&raceid=8444"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

data = []
while True:
    course = []
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "tableJustrun")))

    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    # get table data 
    tbody = page_soup.find("tbody",{"id":"searchResultBoxParticipants"})
    rows = tbody.find_all("tr")

    for row in rows:
        rowData = []
        for td in row.find_all("td"):
            rowData.append(td.text)

        course.append(rowData)
    data.append(course)

    try:
        pagination = driver.find_element_by_class_name("simple-pagination")
        next_page = pagination.find_element_by_link_text("Suivant")
        # iterate next page
        next_page.click()
    except Exception as e:
        break

print(data)
```

**Solution-2:**

Using `pandas` library.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

url = "https://tickets.justrun.ca/quidchrono.php?a=qcResult&raceid=8444"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

data = []
while True:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "tableJustrun")))
    tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
    #append Participants table data
    data.append(tables[0])

    try:
        pagination = driver.find_element_by_class_name("simple-pagination")
        next_page = pagination.find_element_by_link_text("Suivant")
        # iterate next page
        next_page.click()
    except Exception as e:
        break

#Concat dataframe object
result = pd.concat(data)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks bharatk! I'm wondering if I could use next_page = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Suivant") instead. If not,why? The code seems to work, but when I inspect the results, it's puzzling. Last element of first four course:['', '50', '13', 'Pascal GobeilRosemère, 43ans', '146', 'Homme', '13-99', '17:33.9', '+']
['', '50', '13', 'Pascal GobeilRosemère, 43ans', '146', 'Homme', '13-99', '17:33.9', '+']
['', '50', '13', 'Pascal GobeilRosemère, 43ans', '146', 'Homme', '13-99', '17:33.9', '+']
['', '100', '21', 'Victor SavoieMontréal, 13ans', '225', 'Homme', '13-99', '20:02.4', '+']

Comment: I've tested your code on a different race twice and got different results. The first time, all sets of 50 results were the same. The second time, the first and second lists were the same, the third was the expected second, fourth and fifth were the expected third, sixth was the fourth, and the rest was missing. There was 6 pages of results for this race. It looks like something is happening too fast, so it's reappending the same list? Where can I add wait time?

Comment: @Véronique Lamontagne Try the second solution, it will give you more clarity of result.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Love the pandas solution as I was going to use pandas anyway to organize the data. But I didn't know about the .read_html() method yet.